# Clozure CL compiled executable losing certain command line arguments

Tags: common-lisp, ccl

I'm writing a utility program in Common Lisp and building it with Clozure CL; I would like to be able to use the command-line option `-d` with the program, but for some reason *this* particular option won't make it through to `(ccl::command-line-arguments)`. Here is a minimal example:

```
(defun main ()
  (format t "~s~%" (ccl::command-line-arguments))
  (quit))
```

I compiled with

```
(save-application "opts"
  :toplevel-function 'main
  :prepend-kernel t)
```

and here's some sample output:

```
~/dev/scratch$ ./opts -c -a -e
("./opts" "-c" "-a" "-e")
~/dev/scratch$ ./opts -c -d -e
("./opts" "-c" "-e")
~/dev/scratch$ ./opts -b --frogs -c -d -e -f -g -h --eye --jay -k -l
("./opts" "--frogs" "-c" "-e" "-f" "-g" "-h" "--eye" "--jay" "-k" "-l")
```

The `-b` and `-d` options appear to be getting lost. The documentation on [command line arguments](http://ccl.clozure.com/docs/ccl.html#command-line-options) for `ccl` isn't very helpful. I thought maybe because `ccl` itself takes `-b` as an argument, that option might have gotten eaten for some reason, but it doesn't take `-d` (which *is* eaten), and it does take `-e` and `-l` which aren't. Nothing on [saving applications](http://ccl.clozure.com/docs/ccl.html#saving-applications) seemed helpful.

I'm pretty sure it's Clozure-specific (and not, say, the shell eating them), because other stuff seems to be getting all the arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
print sys.argv
```

yields

```
~/dev/scratch$ ./opts.py -a -b -c -d -e
['./opts.py', '-a', '-b', '-c', '-d', '-e']
```

and

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$@"
```

gives

```
~/dev/scratch$ ./opts.sh -a -b -c -d -e
-a -b -c -d -e
```

This is all taking place on lubuntu 15.10 with `bash` as the shell.

If anyone could shed some light on why this is happening or how I can end up with all my command-line switches, I'd be appreciative.

Thanks.

Comment: Note that you may get more specific help from the Clozure CL mailing list: https://lists.clozure.com/mailman/listinfo/openmcl-devel

Comment: The problem doesn't seem limited to applications saved with `SAVE-APPLICATION`. If you run CCL itself and give `-b` or `-d` flags it won't show those in `CCL::COMMAND-LINE-ARGUMENTS` (other flags and arguments are shown). Also, if you give a flag that doesn't exist (like `-a`) it will fail to start and just show the help message, but `-d` doesn't cause that to happen. That leads me to believe CCL probably uses it for something (maybe a shorthand for `--debug`?) even though it isn't mentioned in the docs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the source code of the 1.11 release, `-b` and `-d` are options used by the lisp kernel.

Since I'm unsure about licence issues, I just provide the link to the relevant file: http://svn.clozure.com/publicsvn/openmcl/release/1.11/source/lisp-kernel/pmcl-kernel.c

Command line arguments are processed in the function `process_options`, where for options `-b` (`--batch`) and `-d` (`--debug`) - among others - a variable `num_elide` is set to 1. A bit further down, this leads to overwriting the option with the following argument (`argv[k] = argv[j];`).

The code also shows a possible fix: Supply `--` (two dashes) once as argument before `-b` or `-d`. When above function encounters a `--` it stops processing the rest of the arguments, thus leaving them unchanged to be possibly taken up into "lisp world" shortly after.

---

Turns out this has already been solved at SO before:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5522169/1116364

Comment: Well, I don't really know about "solved", but certainly demystified. The comment above `process_options` even says that it removes everything it recognizes from `argv`, leaving the rest available for Lisp to work with. I knew about the double-dash thing (_that_, at least, is in the docs), but I feel like Lisp is so intwined with the tradition of Do The Right Thing that I should be able to compile a friggin' binary that parses arguments in the expected way. (Although, perhaps, the "expected way" is not from said tradition.)

I'll accept this answer if I can't figure out how to get my way.